# Why may type parameters appear only in method invocations that use a dotted form?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I came across the following statement in the book "Java Generics and Collections: Speed Up the Java Development Process" by O'Reilly Media.

> The Java grammar requires that type parameters may appear only in
>   method invocations that use a dotted form. Even if the method
>   `toList` is defined in the same class that invokes the code, we
>   cannot shorten it as follows:
>
> `List<Integer> ints = <Integer>toList();` // compile-time error
>
> This is illegal because it will confuse the parser.

This is the signature of the method:
`public static <T> List<T> toList(T... arr)`

I do get a parameter mismatch error with above code (none vs expected integer array). The compiler error is logical. However, I don't understand the meaning of last statement in the book in this context - **This is illegal because it will confuse the parser**.

Where is the parser getting confused? It is just plain signature mismatch and shouldn't be allowed. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It just means, that you need to write the name of the class in which `toList` is defined in front of the invokation, e.g. `ClassWhereToListIsDefined.<Integer>toList()`

Comment: Note that from Java 1.8 onwards, there is rarely any need to write `<Integer>toList()` because a simple `toList()` will suffice in most cases.